# opengraph action read_article does not post on Timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, article

I set up a "Read Article" action and I am using the Auth_User to test the app before submitting to FB for approval. The problem: nothing shows on Timeline and I have to manually select "Shown on timeline" in the Activity page before the action shows on timeline. Anybody experienced this behavior or has a fix?

I added publish_actions, publish_stream, I checked the debug, no errors there. I also disabled loading FB meta tags in Wordpress.

Am I missing something?